# Downloading a file from a blob

Tags: python-2.7, azure-cli

I am trying to download a file from a azure storage blob. I am getting below error. I am using python 2.7.5 and azure-cli: 2.0.64. But when I use sudo its working fine. can some one please help me fixing this issue ?.
Thanks in advance !!

cannot import name 'AzureException'

Comment: Can you provide more details? The python code or CLI command that you use.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the sample code to iterate over container and folder structure and finally downloading blob files

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import PublicAccess
import os

#name of your storage account and the access key from Settings->AccessKeys->key1
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='storageaccountname', account_key='AccountKey')

#name of the container
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs('testcontainer')

#code below lists all the blobs in the container and downloads them one after another
for blob in generator:
    print(blob.name)
    print("{}".format(blob.name))
    #check if the path contains a folder structure, create the folder structure
    if "/" in "{}".format(blob.name):
        print("there is a path in this")
        #extract the folder path and check if that folder exists locally, and if not create it
        head, tail = os.path.split("{}".format(blob.name))
        print(head)
        print(tail)
        if (os.path.isdir(os.getcwd()+ "/" + head)):
            #download the files to this directory
            print("directory and sub directories exist")
            block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('testcontainer',blob.name,os.getcwd()+ "/" + head + "/" + tail)
        else:
            #create the diretcory and download the file to it
            print("directory doesn't exist, creating it now")
            os.makedirs(os.getcwd()+ "/" + head, exist_ok=True)
            print("directory created, download initiated")
            block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('testcontainer',blob.name,os.getcwd()+ "/" + head + "/" + tail)
    else:
        block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('testcontainer',blob.name,blob.name)
```

Also you mentioned about downloading a file using Azure cli so i am writing a sample syntax to do so

```
az storage file download \
    --account-name $STORAGEACCT \
    --account-key $STORAGEKEY \
    --share-name "myshare" \
    --path "myDirectory/SampleUpload.txt" \
    --dest "~/clouddrive/SampleDownload.txt"
```

Code sample

```
# Create a directory to store all the blobs
mkdir /downloaded-container && cd /downloaded-container

# Get all the blobs
BLOBS=$(az storage blob list -c $CONTAINER \
    --account-name $ACCOUNT_NAME --sas-token "$SAS_TOKEN" \
    --query [*].name --output tsv)

# Download each one
for BLOB in $BLOBS
do
  echo "********Downloading $BLOB"
  az storage blob download -n $BLOB -f $BLOB -c $CONTAINER --account-name $ACCOUNT_NAME --sas-token "$SAS_TOKEN"
done
```

Further reference please visit below doc

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-cli.md

Answer (score 0):

The `AzureException` class is defined in `azure-common` package, you can see its source code at [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/44e09c3da888e96096771596018740590a17cdfd/azure-common/azure/common/__init__.py).

I need you to do some testing in your environment.

1. Check your current `pip` version via command `pip -V`, the current output should be like `pip 19.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)` if you were using Python 2.7.
2. Check whether `azure-common` package has been installed via command `pip freeze` to list the installed packages in your Python environment, such as `azure-common==1.1.18`.
3. If you wrote your code for downloading a blob file, generally the recommended way is to create a Python virtual environment first and activate it to avoid the confliction of different packages, because there may be a Python 3 pip tool as default for your Linux or other possible issues about your workspace.
4. If you worked in a Python virtual environment, it will not require `root` role or `sudo` permission. Try to command `ls -l` to check the file permission of your Python script, the result as like `-rwxrw-rw- 1 <your user name> 1049089  492 Apr  2 16:52 test.py`. You can refer to the two pages ([1](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions), [2](http://www.linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php)) to know more details about Linux file permissions, and you can `chmod` it.

The helpful information in your description is so less, so that I could not supply more fixing suggestion. Expected for your update post, it can help solving your issue quickly.

Any update or concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked the pip version and azure-common package as you suggested. I see the pip version as 19.1.1 and python 2.7. I see the azure-common package too. It's not a python script, I am running a az command to download the file from a blob. What else can I check. Thanks!!